# Which desktop.ini is getting lost when there's network disconnection?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, samba, desktop.ini

I'm a WinXP user on a Windows domain with a Samba fileserver.  I have an H: drive mapped for my home files and there's some group policy that makes H:\Desktop be my desktop.

The problem is, whenever there's a network issue, or the admin resets Samba, or anything like that, I get "Delayed write failed" messages, which are normal because we have Offline files turned off, but then, all my desktop icons are out of order, even after a restart.

AFAIK the desktop icon order is stored in some desktop.ini, but even with all the folder view options set to Show rather than Hide, there's no desktop.ini in H:\Desktop.

Where does this file live, so I can make a backup of it?  It takes forever to put all my icons back the way I like them, so a minor network glitch becomes a major annoyance.

Comment: Have you asked the IT admin for assistance?  The file exists within the Desktop directory.

Comment: @Ramhound, He went into the directory as su and did an `ls -al` and it's not there.  It's not in Samba's recycler, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, whenever there's a network issue, or the admin resets Samba, or anything like that, I get "Delayed write failed" messages, which are normal because we have Offline files turned off, but then, all my desktop icons are out of order, even after a restart.

Define “out of order”. I’m guessing you mean that they are actually in alphabetical order, which is the default behavior.

> AFAIK the desktop icon order is stored in some desktop.ini
>   AFAIK the desktop icon order is stored in some desktop.ini, but even with all the folder view options set to Show rather than Hide, there's no desktop.ini in H:\Desktop.

That’s because `desktop.ini` does not contain the icon layout, that is stored in the registry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`.

> I'm a WinXP user on a Windows domain with a Samba fileserver. I have an H: drive mapped for my home files and there's some group policy that makes H:\Desktop be my desktop.

The problem is that Explorer stores the icons layouts in the registry, but your registry is not getting written to the server, so when you log back in, you are getting the default layout. Your files are irrelevant in this situation.

> Where does this file live, so I can make a backup of it? It takes forever to put all my icons back the way I like them, so a minor network glitch becomes a major annoyance.

What you can do (aside from using folders to organize your desktop icons) is to use a [desktop-layout program](https://www.google.com/search?q=save%20desktop%20layout) to save and restore your desktop icon layout. Just be sure to pick one that stores its configuration data as a file instead of in the registry, otherwise your back to square-one.

Comment: +1 for where it lives in the registry.  However, if the registry doesn't get written, then won't an older version with my (still) correct layout be there instead?

Comment: And yes, it was suddenly alphabetical.

Comment: Explorer only reads the key when it starts up, so if something happens to mess them up, then it won’t re-read them until the next it starts, but that might now hold the modified one. You can try to force Explorer to write the layout after you have arranged it by right-clicking the destkop and selecting refresh. Then you can try restarting Explorer and it should retain the current layout. However if you are loading the setting when you log in, then you would lose the current one and it would get replaced with whatever is on the server. So, make sure to refresh the desktop while connected.

Comment: Alphabetical means that it was using the default layout because there was no layout to use at all. `The problem is, whenever there's a network issue, or the admin resets Samba… all my desktop icons are out of order, even after a restart.` Do they suddenly shift around as soon as the connection is lost?